# How to implement hidden Group Chat Button behind UITableView like WhatsApp on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, uibutton, uisearchbar

I am interested to implement hidden button behind UITableView like WhatsApp on iPhone. For the first time user go to Chats TabBar, UISearchBar and GroupChat Button are hidden, when user scroll down the TableView, GroupChat Button will appear.

[image]

I try to create that UI via IB but I can't tap the button. Here is the IB View Hierarchy:

```
UIView  
-->UIButton  
-->UITableView  
   -->UIView (UIView as TableView's header)  
      -->UISearchBar
```

I set UIView height to 88 and clearColor as BackgroundColor <-- (UIView that contains UISearchBar). Then I set UISearchBar Y position to 44.
On `- (void)viewDidLoad` I do this

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0) animated:YES];
```

What is the best way to achieve that UI behavior?? Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Interesting, do the buttons and search bar stay at the top as you scroll through the table or are they basically cells at the top of the table?

Comment: Search Bar stay at TableView's header but the buttons stay at the top of UIView behind UITableView

Comment: Try adding Button in UITableView header view and Search bar in section header.

Comment: Trying to do the same thing here, have you figured out how to do this? Thanks.